# Problem with the code while calling Invoke() on form?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method which is called on a different thread than UI thread.

When this method is called the control is gone , I mean nothing happens.

The code is like below:

```
    private void MainForm_NewMeasurementState(Measurement measurement)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        // we were called on a worker thread
                        // marshall the call to the user interface thread
                        this.Invoke(new Action<Measurement>(MainForm_NewMeasurementState), new object[] { measurement });
                        return;
                    }
// some other code
    }
```

The control comes in the `if` statement but then I don't know what happens, the other code is never called.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: WinForms  using .Net Compact Framework..

Comment: `the other code is never called` - How do you *know* that the other code isn't called? Have you tried putting a breakpoint there and seeing if it ever gets hit?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your main thread is blocked, perhaps because it is waiting for your code to complete (i.e. your code is deadlocked because two threads are waiting for each other).

Try to find out why the main UI thread is blocked, or else use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`.